# How to fetch images from firebase storage and show as a thumbnail?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I want to develop an application in which recycler listview fetch data from firebase database shows details to user like name, age, city and profile picture.

How to get profile picture from firebase storage and show in recycler list view and show as thumbnail.

```
     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(final UserViewHolder holder, final int position, Context context) {

    this.context = context;

    final BusinessDetailModel businessDetailModel = list.get(position);

    Picasso.with(context).load(list.get(position).getImageUrl()).resize(80, 80).into(holder.thumbnail);
    holder.businessName.setText(businessDetailModel.businessName);
    holder.businessCity.setText(businessDetailModel.city);
    holder.businessRating.setText(businessDetailModel.ratingValue + "");
```

Solution,

You can add global variable:

```
   private Context context;
```

then assign the context from here:

```
   @Override
    public FeedAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {

View v=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feedholder, parent, false);

ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
// set the Context here 
context = parent.getContext();
return vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to get the download url and use a image loading library to fetch and display the image.

I would recommend using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Answer (score 0):

When you have uploaded image in `Firebase Storage`, they have given you the URL for that image.

Use that path and make code for display thumbnail.

`Firebase` didn't provided the Thumbnail, so you have to make code for that.

Comment: Normally, there is two type of onBindViewHolder, I get.

        public void onBindViewHolder(final OwnerChatViewHolder holder, final int position, final List<Object> payloads) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
    }


    public void onBindViewHolder(OwnerChatViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // bind code 
    }

Comment: Did you extends "RecyclerView.Adapter" to your Adapter?

Comment: I got the solution. Thanks bro for help.